# Draw a stair using Java

Tags: java

I am drawing a stair on Java JPanel from `(0,0)` to the coordinate `(JComponent.getWidth(), JComponent.getHeight())`.
The horizontal and vertical length will stay the same depends on the constant `NUM_STAIRS`.
The initial drawing will be a horizontal line. I am guessing this will use while and if statements (probably nested) but I am not sure how to produce this algorithm.

My thinking:

Version 1:
Firstly draw a horizontal line of `JComponent.getWidth()/NUM_STAIRS` in length when the y-axis meets the requirement of
`(y=n x JComponent.getHeight()/NUM_STAIRS, where 0< n<=NUM_STAIRS)`.
Remember the endpoint coordinates of the drawn line, draw the vertical line of `JComponent.getHeight()/NUM_STAIRS`
in length and then draw the next horizontal line at the endpoint's x coordinate of the same length at
`y = 1 x JComponent.getHeight()/NUM_STAIRS.`
Repeat this action until y=JComponent.getHeight().

Version 2:
Do 2 loops, draw the horizontal lines and vertical lines separately, idea will be similar with the Version 1. But I am confused about how to write this idea into some code.

Could someone help me out please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a lot of ways to achieve this...this solutions suffers from a rounding issue, but the concept will get you moving...

[image]

The basic idea, is as you said, that each step's width and height is percentage of the available space.

Each step starts at position which is multiplier of the step's width/height and the current step.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class StairWayToHeven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StairWayToHeven();
    }

    public StairWayToHeven() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int numSteps = 4;

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            final JSlider slider = new JSlider(2, 20);
            slider.setOpaque(false);
            slider.setValue(4);
            add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    numSteps = slider.getValue();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 

            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int width = getWidth() - (insets.left + insets.right);
            int height = getHeight() - (insets.top + insets.bottom);

            int stepWidth = Math.round((float)width / (float)numSteps);
            int stepHeight = Math.round((float)height / (float)numSteps);

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int step = 0; step < numSteps; step++) {
                int fromX = insets.left + (stepWidth * step);
                int fromY = insets.top + (stepHeight * step);
                int toX = insets.left + (stepWidth * (step + 1));
                int toY = insets.top + (stepHeight * (step + 1));

                g.drawLine(fromX, fromY, toX, fromY);
                g.drawLine(toX, fromY, toX, toY);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the interpretation.